# Making onclick event toggle display on subsequent clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div followed by a fieldset. I have it such you click the div anywhere and it makes the otherwise `display:none` fieldset appear. However, I'd like it to disappear on second click, as well. Basically the onclick event would toggle between `display:none` and `display:block`.

Here's the fiddle I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/zk1j23m5/

```js
function showexpando(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.greyex {
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  display: none;
}
.expando {
  background-color: #A971A9;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.expando a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="expando" onclick="showexpando('excred');">
    <a>&#x25BC; lorem &#x25BC;</a>
</div>
<fieldset class="greyex" id="excred">ipsum</fieldset>
```

Additionally, there's some problem with the border. I'd like the `expando` div to have `border-radius: 7px` when the fieldset is hidden, but have `border-radius:7px 7px 0px 0px; border-bottom: 0px` when the fieldset is visible. Lastly, the border doesn't look right when fieldset is visible: there's like a 1px difference in positioning despite the code being congruent.

How can I accomplish these?

edit; I guess I could query the document if fieldset is `display:none` and fiddle with the CSS accordingly using JS, but it seems unwieldy and I'm sure there's an easier solution.

Comment: For future reference, your whole code should be contained in the question. SO offers an on-site fiddle tool, there's no need to use external sites.

Comment: I would treat the whole thing as an item and add a class to the top level specifying state. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zk1j23m5/33/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead.

I'd suggest toggling a class. For instance:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/80tmrpkL/)

```
var expand = document.querySelector('.expando');

expand.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('visible');
});
```

```
.greyex {
    display: none;
}
.greyex.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

References:

- [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling) (IE9+)
- [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) (IE10+)

Answer (score 1):

Noticed no one answered your second part.

If you're looking to get the borders to line-up, just change the `fieldset` to a `div`.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zk1j23m5/27/).

Or, alternatively you can set the margin to the `fieldset` element to:

```
margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
```

To match the `div`.